# Modify http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test to return latest 5 results

Tags: twitter

Looking at question 
[Get all tweets with specific hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290652/get-all-tweets-with-specific-hashtag)

Is it possible to modify http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test so that just latest 5 results are returned ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) there is no parameter to limit the result.

However, **rpp** limits the results per page. It may not be exactly what you want, but might suffice:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test&rpp=5

Comment: Thanks for that, reading the doc it says that http://search.twitter.com returns 'popular' search results. What is meant by the term 'popular'. Does this mean that all results may not be returned ?

Comment: The parameter "result_type" defaults to "mixed" meaning both real-time and popular results will be returned. Setting that to `recent` will result in the latest matches.