# Get Twitter Users with a specific hashtag

Tags: c#, twitter, get, hashtag

So what I wanna do is get users that has a specific hashtag. any ideas on what to use? I am using `Tweetsharp` and C#.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you share?

Comment: What is a "[user] that has a specific hashtag"? I'm not using Twitter, but aren't hashtags for tweets and not for users? Anyways, how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290652/get-all-tweets-with-specific-hashtag

Comment: haha actually I have no idea how to go further. I don't understand the Oauth Api from Twitter and I don't get any good examples on code.
What I wanna do is to get a users Image,UserName and their tweets when they had a hashtag about a specifik thing. But I don't want users to authenticate to twitter to check information. I know you can get information about a user not signed in so somehow I wanna do this hehe..

Comment: and yes, hashtags are for tweets, so i want the tweets and username / images. :p

Comment: this is my code atm:

 TwitterService service = new TwitterService();
            TwitterSearchResult res = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "Iobffp", Count=3 });
            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = res.Statuses;
            Response.Write(res);

Answer (score 0):

You Used this code
http://forums.asp.net/post/4761697.aspx or
http://abhi4net.blogspot.com/2013/07/twitter-api-11-integration-with-mvc-in-c.html

Using TweetSharp Library you can add library from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/2.3.1)

**Controllar Code**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<TwitterModel> tweets = GetTweets("#twitter");
        return View(tweets);
       // return View();
    }
    public List<TwitterModel> GetTweets(string twitterHashTag)
    {

        List<TwitterModel> lstTweets = new List<TwitterModel>();

        // New Code added for Twitter API 1.1
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(twitterHashTag))
        {
            var twitter = new TwitterHelper(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OauthConsumerKey"],
                                                            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OauthConsumerKeySecret"],
                                                            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OauthAccessToken"],
                                                            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OauthAccessTokenSecret"]);

            var response = twitter.GetTweets(twitterHashTag, 100);
            dynamic timeline = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(response);
            foreach (var tweet in timeline)
            {
                System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonArray tweetJson = tweet.Value as System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonArray;
                if (tweetJson != null && tweetJson.Count() > 0)
                    foreach (System.Dynamic.DynamicObject item in tweetJson)
                    {
                        TwitterModel tModel = new TwitterModel();
                        tModel.Id = ((dynamic)item).id.ToString();
                        tModel.AuthorName = ((dynamic)item).user.name;
                        tModel.AuthorUrl = ((dynamic)item).user.url;
                        tModel.Content = ((dynamic)item).Text;
                        string publishedDate = ((dynamic)item).created_at;
                        publishedDate = publishedDate.Substring(0, 19);
                        tModel.Published = DateTime.ParseExact(publishedDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss", null);

                        tModel.ProfileImage = ((dynamic)item).user.profile_image_url;
                        lstTweets.Add(tModel);
                    }
            }
        }
        return lstTweets;
    }
```

**Classes**

```
  public class TwitterHelper
{
    public const string OauthVersion = "1.0";
    public const string OauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";

    public TwitterHelper(string consumerKey, string consumerKeySecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret)
    {
        this.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.ConsumerKeySecret = consumerKeySecret;
        this.AccessToken = accessToken;
        this.AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret;
    }

    public string ConsumerKey { set; get; }
    public string ConsumerKeySecret { set; get; }
    public string AccessToken { set; get; }
    public string AccessTokenSecret { set; get; }

    public string GetTweets(string twitterHashTag, int count)
    {
        string resourceUrl = string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json");
        var requestParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        requestParameters.Add("q", twitterHashTag);
        requestParameters.Add("count", count.ToString());
        requestParameters.Add("result_type", "mixed");
        var response = GetResponse(resourceUrl, "GET", requestParameters);
        return response;
    }

    private string GetResponse(string resourceUrl, string methodName, SortedDictionary<string, string> requestParameters)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        WebRequest request = null;
        string resultString = string.Empty;

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl + "?" + requestParameters.ToWebString());
        request.Method = methodName;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


        if (request != null)
        {
            var authHeader = CreateHeader(resourceUrl, methodName, requestParameters);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var sd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resultString = sd.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        return resultString;
    }

    private string CreateOauthNonce()
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    }

    private string CreateHeader(string resourceUrl, string methodName, SortedDictionary<string, string> requestParameters)
    {
        var oauthNonce = CreateOauthNonce();
        // Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString())); 
        var oauthTimestamp = CreateOAuthTimestamp();
        var oauthSignature = CreateOauthSignature(resourceUrl, methodName, oauthNonce, oauthTimestamp, requestParameters);
        //The oAuth signature is then used to generate the Authentication header. 
        const string headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " + "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " + "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " + "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";
        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthNonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(OauthSignatureMethod), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthTimestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(ConsumerKey), Uri.EscapeDataString(AccessToken), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignature), Uri.EscapeDataString(OauthVersion));
        return authHeader;
    }
    private string CreateOauthSignature(string resourceUrl, string method, string oauthNonce, string oauthTimestamp, SortedDictionary<string, string> requestParameters)
    {
        //firstly we need to add the standard oauth parameters to the sorted list 
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", ConsumerKey);
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", oauthNonce);
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", OauthSignatureMethod);
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauthTimestamp);
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_token", AccessToken);
        requestParameters.Add("oauth_version", OauthVersion);
        var sigBaseString = requestParameters.ToWebString();
        var signatureBaseString = string.Concat(method, "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceUrl), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(sigBaseString.ToString()));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(ConsumerKeySecret), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(AccessTokenSecret));
        string oauthSignature;
        using (var hasher = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauthSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBaseString)));
        }
        return oauthSignature;
    }
    private static string CreateOAuthTimestamp()
    {
        var nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var timeSpan = nowUtc - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString(); return timestamp;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToWebString(this SortedDictionary<string, string> source)
    {
        var body = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var requestParameter in source)
        {
            body.Append(requestParameter.Key);
            body.Append("=");
            body.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(requestParameter.Value));
            body.Append("&");
        } //remove trailing '&' 
        body.Remove(body.Length - 1, 1); return body.ToString();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<TwitterHashTag.Models.TwitterModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>


</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AuthorName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AuthorUrl)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProfileImage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Published)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AuthorName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AuthorUrl)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProfileImage)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Published)
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```